# Написать бота для инстаграм

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, instagram

Хочу попробовать сделать бота для instagram, что-то подобное как [здесь](https://zengram.ru) с можеством функций для выбора. Нашел библиотеку на [github](https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API) для php, но насколько мне известно php не обладает многопоточностью, мне же важно сделать к примеру накрутку пользователей в фоновом режиме, чтобы можно было и дальше передвигаться по сайту или вовсе закрыть его, а он в свою очередь будет выполняться пока не достигнет своего лимита. В первой ссылке все так и организовано, на каком языке можно такое реализовать? Думаю на счет python, что можете подсказать по этому поводу?

Comment: cron вам в помощь, и будет ваш PHP скрипт выполняться в фоновом режиме

Comment: @Walfter, вы думаете такие сервисы работают через cron?

Comment: Если что то должно выполнятся в фоне без пользователя то пусть это будет крон

Comment: Практически на любом языке можно это реализовать, интересный вопрос...  php "не поддерживает" многопоточность "с коробки", но её реализовать можно

Comment: @InDevX не возникнет ли с этим проблем позже?

Comment: @TeaMan Если изначально сделать "не правильно" - конечно возникнут. Другое дело, а стоит ли? на "С-образных" языкам можно написать для этого модуль какой-то, который в десятки раз будет выигрывать по производительности у того же php.. В своё время писал cron под себя, с многопотоком, потратил много времени, но производительность не впечатляла и по началу приходилось покупать хорошие сервера именно для cron'a. А потом как-то так получилось что коллега помог, переписал всё для cloud сервисов на asp.net; результат приятно удивил.

Comment: @InDevX, по этому и спрашивал за питон, у меня есть не большой опыт работы с ним, вопрос подходойдет ли он для этого?Очень важно, чтобы он работал даже когда клиент закрывает браузер, чтобы работал на сервере все время

Comment: @TeaMan, Увы, за питон ничего не скажу, с ним дел не имел. Но уверен что и он подойдёт для решения задачи.

Answer (score 1):

Вот работающий пример бота делающий лайки в фоновом режиме

```py
import argparse
from instabot import Bot

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=True)
parser.add_argument('-u', type=str, help="username")
parser.add_argument('-p', type=str, help="password")
parser.add_argument('-proxy', type=str, help="proxy")
parser.add_argument('-location', type=str, help='location')
parser.add_argument('-amount', type=str, help='amount')
args = parser.parse_args()

bot = Bot()
bot.login(username=args.u, password=args.p,
          proxy=args.proxy)

bot.like_location_feed(args.location, amount=args.amount)
```

Для того чтобы запустить его в работу проверьте чтобы у вас был установлен Python 3 и выполните следующие действия:

- Создайте рабочую папку "MySuperBot" и сохраните предложенный код в файл `go_likes.py`
- Инициируйте в ней рабочее окружение с помощью `python -m venv venv`
- Активируйте виртуальное окружение, это надо будет делать каждый раз когда вы захотите поработать с терминалом. На Linux и MacOS это делается командой `source venv/bin/activate`, под Windows `.\venv\Scripts\activate`
- Установите нужный пакет `pip install -U instabot`
- Теперь можно запустить накрутку `python go_likes.py -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD -amount 400`.

Программа будет работать в терминале пока вы ее не закроете и будет в сутки делать не более 400 лайков. Обратите внимание, что если у вас новый аккаунт то лучше начинать с 50-100 и постепенно в течении нескольких недель доводить до 500. Больше может вызвать тревогу. Эта программа автоматически лайкает все новые посты в вашем фиде.

Более подробная [документация по библиотеке instabot](https://instagrambot.github.io/docs/ru/) на русском языке.